# How can I properly format a CSV file in PHP for an import into Excel?

Tags: php, excel, csv, import

I am trying to export data from PHP generating a CSV file. However, when I import that into Excel, it looks like that:

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JDiu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hlaH.png)

**This is my php code:**

```
<?php  
   if($error == '')
   {
      $file_open = fopen("Sortering_formulier.csv", "a");
      $rows = count(file("Sortering_formulier.csv"));
      if($rows > 1)
      {
       $rows = ($rows - 1) + 1;
      }  
      $form_data = array(
       'sr_no' => $rows,
       'auditeurso'  => $auditeurso,
       'datum'  => $datum,
       'zone'  => $zone,
       'textso01'  => $textso01,
       'ok'  => $ok,
       'results' => $results,
       'okk'  => $okk,
       'okc'  => $okc,
       'comment' => $comment
      ); 
      fputcsv($file_open, $form_data);
      $error = '<label class="text-success">Thank you for filling in the Sorting form</label>';
      $auditeurso = '';
      $datum = '';
      $zone = '';
      $textso01 = '';
      $ok = '';
      $results = '';
      $okk = '';
      $okc = '';
      $comment = '';
     }
   }
?>
```

Comment: Where is `$form_data` coming from? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I will give my full php code here

Comment: Now Excel? Ok step by step. Are you trying to import a CSV generated by PHP into Excel?

Comment: I hope the picture helps and that you understand what I mean.
and I am new here.

Comment: yes from a contact form.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please also read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: You have to use the same setting in PHP [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) (delimiter, enclosure) and in the import settings in Excel. [Import Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) Someone with Excel installed could form a complete answer.

Comment: so I have to change my PHP code before all the texts are placed below each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to understand how CSV file works. CHS file is just a text file with comma separated values on each line. When you try to import a CSV file into Excel/Spreadsheet. They read every line as a single row and they arrange each comma separated values into columns for each line. Now what you are doing in your code is, passing the array to `putcsv()` method in the wrong way. Take look at the array you are passing,

```
$form_data = array(
       'sr_no' => $rows,
       'auditeurso'  => $auditeurso,
       'datum'  => $datum,
       'zone'  => $zone,
       'textso01'  => $textso01,
       'ok'  => $ok,
       'results' => $results,
       'okk'  => $okk,
       'okc'  => $okc,
       'comment' => $comment
      );
```

In your code you are passing an associate array into `putcsv()` function whereas you need to pass a multidimensional array to that function. In the array you are passing every element of array is considered as single value for each column thats the reason you are getting some jumbled text in the Excel. You can try to pass the array in this format,

```
$form_data = array(
    ['sr_no', 'auditeurso', 'datum', 'zone', 'textso01', 'ok', 'results', 'okk', 'okc', 'comment'], /* this represent the column headers in the Excel*/
    [$rows, $auditeurso, $datum, $zone, $textso01, $ok, $results, $okk, $okc, $comment]
);
```

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Angulr-421-N-WORK-APP\html\form_sorting.php on line 115